# XSLT transformation to an array fails for single entry

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following input SOAP xml.

```
 Input xml


  <env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header>
    <wsse:Security
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-43">
            <wsse:Username>{simWSUser}</wsse:Username>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <ns5:UserRequest>
        <ns5:LogonUserName>{LogonUserName}</ns5:LogonUserName>
        <ns5:Context>{Context}</ns5:Context>
        <ns5:UserKey>{Key}</ns5:UserKey>
        <ns5:PermissionCode>value-1</ns5:PermissionCode>
        <ns5:PermissionCode>value-2</ns5:PermissionCode>
        <ns5:PermissionCode>value-3</ns5:PermissionCode>
        <ns5:PermissionCode>value-4</ns5:PermissionCode>
    </ns5:UserRequest>
</env:Body>
```

I applied the following XSLT transformation for creating an array of permissionCodes

```
  <xsl:for-each select="ns5:UserRequest/ns5:PermissionCode">
      <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:element name="PermissionCodes">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

But creation of array fails for single entries(one input PermissionCode). But works for more than one.

Could anyone help why this failing for single value of PermissionCode?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your code does **not** create "an array of permissionCodes". It creates an element for each individual PermissionCode - and it will do so regardless of how many of them there are.

Comment: What is an "array of permission codes"? A list of the codes? A table? A formated file?

Comment: a formatted file like    hotel": [
{
"X": "1",
"permissionCodes": ["3456","4456"],
"city": "WALTHAM"
}

]